# How to call wp_list_comments() outside of the comments template?

Tags: pages, comments, comments-template

I'm simply typing wp_list_comments() in page.php but nothing is shown. But if I put the comments_template() tag there, then the comment form, comments and pings are shown. Why is that, why can't I use wp_list_comments() in page.php? What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include comments functionality via `comments_template()`, because this function doesn't merely include the `comments.php`, file, but also handles all of the querying and functions required for displaying comments.

While [the Codex doesn't really get into details](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template), you can see, [by looking at source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L823), what's going on:

```
<?php
/**
 * Loads the comment template specified in $file.
 *
 * Will not display the comments template if not on single post or page, or if
 * the post does not have comments.
 *
 * Uses the WordPress database object to query for the comments. The comments
 * are passed through the 'comments_array' filter hook with the list of comments
 * and the post ID respectively.
 *
 * The $file path is passed through a filter hook called, 'comments_template'
 * which includes the TEMPLATEPATH and $file combined. Tries the $filtered path
 * first and if it fails it will require the default comment template from the
 * default theme. If either does not exist, then the WordPress process will be
 * halted. It is advised for that reason, that the default theme is not deleted.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 * @global array $comment List of comment objects for the current post
 * @uses $wpdb
 * @uses $post
 * @uses $withcomments Will not try to get the comments if the post has none.
 *
 * @param string $file Optional, default '/comments.php'. The file to load
 * @param bool $separate_comments Optional, whether to separate the comments by comment type. Default is false.
 * @return null Returns null if no comments appear
 */
?>
```

Comment: So basically, it's not possible to use wp_list_comments() outside of comments.php?

Comment: I won't say that it's not *possible*. Also: it would be more accurate to say that the comments template is expected to be included via `comments_template()` (since the filename doesn't *have* to be `comments.php`; you can pass a different filename as a parameter to `comments_template()`).

Comment: So, just for the record, is it possible to use wp_list_comments inside page.php to list comments? How?

Comment: I leave that as an exercise for the user, since it will involve re-implementing the functionality within the `comments_template()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing wp_list_comments() like this:

```
<ol class="commentlist">
<?php wp_list_comments();?>
</ol>
```

comments_template() simply loads comments.php which makes use of wp_list_comments in an enclosing CSS class.

HTH